# CoreGraphics - Can't replace UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32> with UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I just started messing around with image processing and I'm having a couple very odd problems or at least I think they are. I'm assuming I've made some really dumb mistake.

I was going to post another question about this but, with the code below sometimes I also get random noise instead of the pixel representation of the user drawn number. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me why that happens as well. I'm having a hard time finding out why because everything that I read suggests this code should work.

If anyone needs any more information please let me know! Thank you for your help in advance!

**Goal:**
First, obtain a number drawn by the user on the screen. Then, resize the image to 28 x 28. Next, convert the image to gray scale and get an array of the normalized pixel values. Finally, feed the normalized gray scale pixel values in to a machine learning algorithm.

*[NOTE: In the pictures below, the dots represent a 0 value and 1s represent a value > 0.]*

The output of the code below works pretty well. If the user draws a "3" I usually get something like the following:

[image: UInt32]

**Problem:**

If I change the size of the UnsafeMutablePointer and Buffer to UInt8 I get what looks like random noise. Or if I replace the UnsafeMutablePointer and Buffer with `[UInt32](repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)` or even `[UInt8](repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)` every pixel ends up being 0, which I really don't understand.

Here is the output of the pixels if I change the size of the UnsafeMutablePointer and Buffer to UInt8:

[image: UInt8]

**Code for obtaining grayscale pixels:**

```
public extension UIImage
{
    private func grayScalePixels() -> UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>?
    {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }

        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let width = cgImage.width
        let height = cgImage.height
        let totalBytes = (width * height)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: totalBytes)
        defer { data.deallocate(capacity: totalBytes) }

        guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: data, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: 0) else { return nil }
        imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height)))

        return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: data, count: totalBytes)
    }

    public func normalizedGrayScalePixels() -> [CGFloat]?
    {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
        guard let pixels = self.grayScalePixels() else { return nil }

        let width = cgImage.width
        let height = cgImage.height
        var result = [CGFloat]()

        for y in 0..<height
        {
            for x in 0..<width
            {
                let index = ((width * y) + x)
                let pixel = (CGFloat(pixels[index]) / 255.0)
                result.append(pixel)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

**Code for drawing the number:**

```
    func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, 1)

        self.tempImageView.image?.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.move(to: fromPoint)
        context?.addLine(to: toPoint)
        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(self.brushWidth)
        context?.setStrokeColor(gray: 0, alpha: 1)
        context?.strokePath()

        self.tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        self.tempImageView.alpha = self.opacity

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        self.swiped = false

        if let touch = touches.first {
            self.lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        self.swiped = true

        if let touch = touches.first
        {
            let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
            self.drawLineFrom(fromPoint: self.lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

            self.lastPoint = currentPoint
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        if !swiped {
            self.drawLineFrom(fromPoint: self.lastPoint, toPoint: self.lastPoint)
        }

        self.predictionLabel.text = "Predication: \(self.predict())"

        self.tempImageView.image = nil
    }
```

**Code to predict number:**

```
    private func printNumber(rowSize: Int, inputs: Vector)
    {
        for (index, pixel) in inputs.enumerated()
        {
            if index % rowSize == 0 { print() }

            if (pixel > 0) {
                print("1", terminator: " ")
            }
            else { print(".", terminator: " ") }
        }

        print()
    }

    private func predict() -> Scalar
    {
        let resizedImaege = self.tempImageView.image!.resizedImage(CGSize(width: 28, height: 28), interpolationQuality: .high)
        let inputs = resizedImaege!.normalizedGrayScalePixels()!.flatMap({ Scalar($0) })
        self.feedforwardResult = self.neuralNetwork!.feedForward(inputs: inputs)

        self.printNumber(rowSize: 28, inputs: inputs)

        let max = self.feedforwardResult!.activations.last!.max()!
        let prediction = self.feedforwardResult!.activations.last!.index(of: max)!
        return Scalar(prediction)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing critically bad in your code is this line:

```
    defer { data.deallocate(capacity: totalBytes) }
```

`data.deallocate(capacity: totalBytes)` is executed just before exiting the method `grayScalePixels()`. So, the `baseAddress` of the returned `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` is pointing to an already deallocated region, which means you cannot expect any predictable result when access the region.

If you want to use `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, you need to deallocate the region after finishing all accesses to it (#1 in the code below):

```
private func grayScalePixels() -> UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt8>? {
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
    
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    let totalBytes = width * height
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: totalBytes)
    data.initialize(to: UInt8.max, count: totalBytes)   //<- #4
    
    guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: data, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: 0) else { return nil }
    imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    
    return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: data, count: totalBytes)
}

public func normalizedGrayScalePixels() -> [CGFloat]? {
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
    guard let pixels = self.grayScalePixels() else { return nil }
    
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    var result: [CGFloat] = []
    
    for y in 0..<height {
        for x in 0..<width {
            let index = width * y + x
            let pixel = CGFloat(pixels[index]) / CGFloat(UInt8.max)
            result.append(pixel)
        }
    }
    pixels.baseAddress!.deinitialize(count: pixels.count)   //<- #2
    pixels.baseAddress!.deallocate(capacity: pixels.count)  //<- #1
    
    return result
}
```

(#2) `deinitialize` may not be needed for `UInt8` in the current implementation of Swift, but the sequence: allocate - initialize - deinitilize - deallocate is the recommended way.

(Some other lines touched are just my preference and not critical.)

---

Or else, if you want to work with Swift `Array` rather than `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, you can write something like this:

```
private func grayScalePixels() -> [UInt8]? {
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
    
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    let totalBytes = width * height
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    var byteArray: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: UInt8.max, count: totalBytes) //<- #4
    let success = byteArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {(buffer)->Bool in
        guard let imageContext = CGContext(data: buffer.baseAddress!, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: 0) else { return false }
        imageContext.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        return true;
    }
    return success ? byteArray : nil
}

public func normalizedGrayScalePixels() -> [CGFloat]? {
    guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
    guard let pixels = self.grayScalePixels() else { return nil }
    
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    var result: [CGFloat] = []
    
    for y in 0..<height {
        for x in 0..<width {
            let index = width * y + x
            let pixel = CGFloat(pixels[index]) / CGFloat(UInt8.max)
            result.append(pixel)
        }
    }
    
    return result
}
```

---

You may need to modify my codes above to make them work with your code, as I cannot reproduce the same result with your `UInt32` version of `grayScalePixels()`.

---

#### EDIT

I have found a problem in my code. Your drawing code draws line with:

```
    context?.setStrokeColor(gray: 0, alpha: 1)
```

Gray scale 0, black. And in my old code, I initialized the bitmaps as:

```
    data.initialize(to: 0, count: totalBytes)
```

or:

```
    var byteArray: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)
```

So, drawing black on black, result: all black, in 8-bit gray scale, all 0s.
(I first wrote `initialize` might not be needed, but that was a mistake. Images with alpha will be drawn mixed with the initial bitmap content.)

My updated code (marked with `#4`) initializes the bitmaps with white (in 8-bit gray scale, `255` == `0xFF` == `UInt8.max`).

And you'd better detect non-white pixels with updating your `printNumber(rowSize:inputs:)`:

```
private func printNumber(rowSize: Int, inputs: Vector) {
    for (index, pixel) in inputs.enumerated() {
        if index % rowSize == 0 { print() }
        
        if pixel < 1.0 { //<- #4
            print("1", terminator: "")
        }
        else { print(".", terminator: "") }
    }
    
    print()
}
```

In normalized gray scale as float, `1.0` is the value for white and you'd better show non-white as `1`. (Or, find another better threshold.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I'm still getting random noise with the code you've provided. Although, what you've mentioned makes complete sense and leads me to believe that it's the way I'm drawing my image. I've edited my question to provide this code. Would you mind taking a quick look at it? I found it on Ray Wenderlich's site.

Comment: Also, if I keep data.initialize(to: 0, count: totalBytes) the returned pixel array is all 0s. If I remove it I get random noise. If I remove it and change the pointer back to UInt32 I get the correct output "most" of the time. So, I essentially still have the same problems. For the second bit of code, which is what I'd prefer to use, I get all 0s as well.

Comment: @Jonathan, I have found that my code does not work for some _resize_ d images. Showing the definition of your `predict()` would be some help.

Comment: Sure, no problem! I've edited my question with the code. Also, this is where I've obtained the code to resize my image: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: I tried without resizing and I still have the same issue. If it helps I printed out the following for the original CGImage (without resizing): bitsPerComponent = 8, bitsPerPixel = 32, bytesPerRow = 128, CFDataGetLength(cgImage.dataProvider!.data) = 3584

Comment: Right on! Thank you for the help! Everything works exactly as expected now. As for the non-white needing to be one, I subtracted the value from 1 to flip the grayscale value (e.g. black = (1 - value)).